# Internal server error response during rails omniauth docusign callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docusignapi, omniauth

I am connecting to DocuSign via oauth with Rails 6 and Omniauth - it seems I have it configured correctly since visiting `/auth/docusign` takes me to the DocuSign login screen. After logging in, it takes me to the callback. The callback is failing because the omniauth-docusign gem is failing with the `user_info` hash. Where it should be getting `user_info['accounts']` it is getting this:

`user_info #=> {"error"=>"internal_server_error", "reference_id"=>"a0f0e8c9-2faa-4b70-90b8-875ae40f13cf"}`

My API Dashboard for the App shows no log or request info. 0 total requests. Is there a log area for oauth attempts, or where to use this reference ID?

Can someone at DocuSign help with this? Your developer support page seems to say to ask here on S/O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you didn't configure everything correctly for your Integration Key (IK which is like **clientId**) as well as **clientSecret** and the rest of the configuration that you can do for your IK.
I would suggest that you can get a pre-built Ruby application that already had this all done for you and save you some work by going to the [Quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/). This would enable you to go get a ZIP file pre-configurated with all the required gems and everything needed for auth already set based on your own developer account.

**Update:** if you then want to take this code into your own app, you need to also get the authentication code supplied lib/docusign.rb instead of a gem like omniauth-docusign.

Comment: Thanks, I am working with the quickstart app and trying to bring over the parts I need for my existing app.

Comment: I figured out that I need to use the Quickstart supplied lib/docusign.rb instead of a gem like omniauth-docusign. Things seem to be working now, my callback gets a full "auth_hash" object.

Answer (score 1):

As Inbar Gazit said, it's important to use the Quickstart app, which I was doing. However, not only do I already have my own existing rails app, even if I didn't, I wouldn't want to have to clean out all the extra stuff in the quickstart app that I don't need. It would be nice to have a minimal script for installing just the bare minimum into an existing rails app to get authenticated and start using the API.

In the end, the solution for me was to notice and copy the `lib/docusign.rb` file from the Quickstart app, instead of using an `omniauth-docusign` gem. The base omniauth gem had advised me to find and install that gem because there was no strategy defined for docusign. The quickstart lib file is what I needed.